# UI5 - is there an equivalent of Page property showNavButton for ObjectPage?

Tags: navigation, sapui5

I have one beginners question. I started working on the UI5 webapp and kept using **showNavButton property** of the *sap.m.Page* control, which displays the navigation button on the right side of the header.

Now, I created one page as the *sap.uxap.ObjectPage* and also would like to have the nav button in the left side of the header. However, the ObjectPageHeader is missing this property. Could you advise me some way to put it there? Does sap.uxap.ObjectPageHeader have some equivalent for the showNavButton property or how can I otherwise put it there? Is there a way to simply "enable" it or will I have to put it there manually?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as `sap.uxap.ObjectPage`.

What you probably mean is `sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout`. While `sap.m.Page` is a container, `sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout` is (as the name suggests) a layout.

So simply put your `ObjectPageLayout` inside a regular `Page`.

```
<mvc:View ...>
    <Page showNavButton="true">
        <uxap:ObjectPageLayout>
            ...
        </uxap:ObjectPageLayout>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```